# Trying to get property of non-object (Parsing)

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, html-parser

I have some problem about parsing, I need get photo link, but error is in code.
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: views/varle2_view.php
Line Number: 25

```
 <h2>Telefonai Varle</h2>
</br>
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
 $url = "https://www.varle.lt/mobilieji-telefonai/";

 // Start from the main page
 $nextLink = $url;

 // Loop on each next Link as long as it exsists
while ($nextLink) {
echo "<hr>nextLink: $nextLink<br>";
//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a url
$html->load_file($nextLink);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Get phone blocks and extract info (also insert to db) ///
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$phones = $html->find('a[data-id]');

foreach($phones as $phone) {

   $photo=$phone->find('span[img=data-original]',0)->plaintext;
    // Get the link
    $linkas = $phone->href;

    // Get the name
    $pavadinimas = $phone->find('span[class=inner]', 0)->plaintext;
    $pavadinimas = str_replace("Išmanusis telefonas"," ",$pavadinimas);

    // Get the name price and extract the useful part using regex
    $kaina = $phone->find('span[class=price]', 0)->plaintext;
    // This captures the integer part of decimal numbers: In "123,45" will capture "123"... Use @([\d,]+),?@ to capture the decimal part too
    preg_match('@(\d+),?@', $kaina, $matches);
    $kaina = $matches[1];

    echo $pavadinimas, " #----# ", $kaina, " #----# ", $linkas, "#----#", $photo, "     <br>";

//$query = "insert into telefonai (pavadinimas,kaina,parduotuve,linkas) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
 //     $this->db->query($query, array($pavadinimas,$kaina,"Varle.lt", $linkas));
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Extract the next link, if not found return NULL
  $nextLink = ( ($temp = $html->find('div.pagination a[class="next"]', 0)) ?    "https://www.varle.lt".$temp->href : NULL );

// Clear DOM object
$html->clear();
unset($html);
}
?>
```

source of web

```
 <a href="https://www.varle.lt/mobilieji-telefonai/htc-desire-500-dual-sim-glossy-juodas-506e.html" class="grid-item product  " data-id="606846"
    title=" HTC DESIRE 500 Dual SIM GLOSSY JUODAS 506e - Mobilieji telefonai">



<span class="left-border"></span>
<span class="left-border-hover"></span>
<span class="right-border-hover"></span>
<span class="top-border-hover"></span>
<span class="bottom-border-hover"></span>


    <span class="wishlist_button_cont">
        <span class="add_to_wishlist witem606846" data-id="606846">
            <span class="icon insert"></span>
        </span>
    </span>


<span class="img-container" style="position: relative;">


        <img src="/static/app/img/white_space.png?lazyyy" class="lazy" data-original="/static/uploads/products/235x195/2/htc/htc-desire-500-dual-sim-glossy-black-506e_3.jpg"
            alt=" HTC DESIRE 500 Dual SIM GLOSSY JUODAS 506e - Mobilieji telefonai" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obtain this warning because your find query doesn't return any node object, since there is no span tag with `img` as attribute.

If I understand well, you are trying to find the text content of a span node that has as child an img node that has an `data-original' attribute. So the syntax is (since img is a node and not an attribute):

```
$photo=$phone->find('span img[data-original]',0)->plaintext;
```

If your goal is to obtain the image link (that is hidden inside the `data-original` non standard attribute, you must use:

```
$photo=$phone->find('span img[data-original]',0)->attr['data-original'];
```

Comment: Thanks, And one more litle question about insert in DB. Now i have "/static/uploads/products/235x195/26/sam/samsung-galaxy-s4.png", but I want this in my table https :// varle. lt/static/uploads/products/235x195/26/sam/samsung-galaxy-s4.png. Is it hard?

Comment: @Mangirdas: Oh yes it is very hard you must concatenate two character strings that is a very difficult task in PHP :)

Comment: stupid question, I agree, just looking at this too much difficulty

Answer (score 0):

You are obtaining $photo as a string like this:

```
$photo=$phone->find('span[img=data-original]',0)->plaintext;
```

And then you are trying to treat it like object:

```
$linkas = $phone->href;
```

It can't be done. Don't use `plaintext` if you want an object.

Comment: thanks, Maybe know how to parse correctly photo link?

Comment: What if you just remove `->plaintext` part?

Comment: if i removed- no error, but then i print is just empty where should be photo link